# How can I check whether a user has login permissions on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, apache-http-server

I want to make sure that the user www-data cannot be used to login on my system (Ubuntu Lucid). How can I find out? - is there a command I can run against this user? (traditionally run by Apache daemon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`passwd -l www-data`

Comment: From `man passwd`: "Note that this does not disable the account. The user may still be able to login using another authentication token (e.g. an SSH key). To disable the account, administrators should use usermod --expiredate 1 (this set the account´s expire date to Jan 2, 1970)."

Comment: It's effectively disabled since he'd have to add a key to log in with it

Comment: Hold on, when you talk about the account being 'disabled' - do you mean that Apache can no longer run as the user 'www-data'? (thats not what I want). I want Apache to continue running as the user www-data, but I dont want anyone to be able to log into the system using www-data as a username. I have seen attempts in my log of users trying a brute force attempt to hack into my server using the username www-data - that is what prompted this question.

Comment: By disabled I mean to say that login is disabled.

Answer (score 8):

The information you want is in the `/etc/passwd` file (which is world readable - the hashes of passwords are actually kept in `/etc/shadow`. So you can

```
$ grep www-data /etc/passwd
```

which should produce something along the lines of

```
www-data:x:111:112::/home/www-data:/bin/false
```

(I don't have apache installed, so the details are probably different). The important detail is the part after the last `:` which is the login shell. In this case it is `/bin/false`, which means you can't login as that user. If you look at the line corresponding to your username, you will see it is `/bin/bash` thus allowing you to login.

If www-data has a valid login shell then just go and edit `/etc/passwd` and change the login shell to `/bin/false`.

Comment: And use `vipw` to edit the file so you don't mess it up!

Comment: Won't work if the authdb is in e.g. LDAP.